# Relacionamento um para um Laravel

Tags: laravel, entidade-relacionamento

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro projeto no laravel, e estou com uma dificuldade no relacionamento de duas entidades.

[image: Modelo do banco]

Eu tenho meu cadastro de aluno, mas não estou conseguindo entender como faço pra chamar o cursofac através de um dropdown no cadastro de aluno.

Answer (score 1):

Então,

Eu acho que você vai ter um pouco de trabalho extra por não seguir os padrões de nomeclatura das colunas e nomes de tabela. Que por padrão deve ser:

- tabelas: plural
- primary key: id
- foreign key: nome da tabela no singular concatenado com '_id'

Caso: Um curso tem varios alunos e um aluno pertence à um curso.

Banco de dados

```
cursos          alunos
  id              id
  nome            curso_id
                  nome
```

Models levando em conta que você está usando laravel 5.1

```
class Curso extends Model
{
    public function alunos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Aluno');
    }
}

class Aluno extends Model
{
    public function curso()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Curso');
    }
}
```

Bem é isso, dá uma lida na documentação pois é melhor explicado.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: Valeu Walmir Neto, mas como estou iniciando estou com certa dificuldade de saber como trabalhar isso na view. Quando estiver cadastrando o aluno como posso chamar isso vindo da entidade curso. E relação as entidades elas estão no plural. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não se preocupe!

Na sua model, declare o método com conforme Resposta 1 acima, porém passe os campos das suas tabelas envolvidos no relacionamento como parâmetro.

```
class Curso extends Model
{
    public function alunos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Aluno', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one